# Are there any ultra 320 scsi hba that have Windows Server 2016 compatible drivers?

Tags: scsi, hba

We've been using Adaptec 29320LPE cards but the latest compatible OS is 2008.  We have this card running in a 2016 box in-house and it works fine.  The issue is we need to update a client and I'm hesitant to put in a card that is not supported for their OS. I've found cards from Adaptec, HP, LSI, and ATTO but all lack compatible drivers for 2016 much less 2019.  Has this type of SCSI become obsolete?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Those things were ancient in 2009, let alone 2019. It's a little strange that you are still using hardware from 15-20 years ago as if it was new.

Comment: We have current options but this client and several others are quite happy with their optical jukeboxes that use SCSI connections to their servers.

Answer (score 1):

It’s probably better to move on to current standards for a new machine, yes. SAS is what you’d be looking for today.

The Ultra SCSI standards were introduced in 2003, as far as I recall, and a lot has happened since.

Comment: Moving on would be a very expensive option for this client, they are very attached to their optical jukebox.

Comment: Yes, that’s the drawback with technology: Warranties expire, equipment and software loses support, and/or it simply dies of old age. As long as your customer is aware of the risks involved in running unsupported solutions, it’s their money and their choice - but I would strongly recommend that they budget for a more modern replacement in case something happens to their current solution.